How do I integrate with Meta Ads with a never expiring access token?
I wish to integrate with Meta Ads to get data on Ads spends, Campaigns, etc. I am able to integrate with Meta with Expiring Access Tokens which are Valid for 60 days. After which the user has to re-authorize after 60 days which is a hassle. I need access to only read scopes to fetch the data. The app access doesn't include writing or mutations. Is there any way that I can have Access tokens that are never expiring, for my use case so that the users who authorize their ads accounts on my app, don't need to re-authorize every 60 days.
I noticed that this is possible as few of our competitors are able to do this. (I can confirm this as an existing user in one of the apps)
I wish to access ads_read scope.
The Long lived tokens expire in 60 days, after which the user has to re-authorize it. I failed to find a method to programmatically re-authorize it.
